# Add value +1 to jquery hidden clone field

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add +1 to hidden field value every time when i clone. for example the last clone filed value is 2 and when i clone the new clone field value is 3 which is working fine.

But problem is:
For example these are existing cloned fields.

field value 1
field value 2
field value 3
field value 4

and if i delete 3 and add new then it will be:

field value 1
field value 2
field value 4
field value 4

I don't want the same value again.

```
<ul id="#wrapper">
    <li class="wrap">
        <input type="text" class="dateField" value="" name="date" />
        <input type="text" class="timeField" value="" name="time" />
        <input type="hidden" class="wrapId" value="1" name="wrapId" />
    </li>
</li>
<input id="addWrap" type="button" value="Make Clone" />


// Add Wrap
    var $wraper = $('#wraper');
    $('#addWrap').click(function (e) {
        var $cloneElem = $wraper.children('.wrap').last().clone();
        var $oldID = $('.wrapId').length;
        var $newID = Number($oldID + 1);
        $cloneElem.find('.wrapId').val($newID).end()
            .insertAfter($wraper.children('.wrap').last());

        adjustContainerHeight();
        e.preventDefault();
    });


    // Delete Wrap
    $wraper.delegate('.removeWrap', 'click', function (e) {
        if ($wraper.children('.wrap').length == 1) {
            $class.find('input.dateField').val('').end()
                .find('input.timeField').val('').end()
                .find('.wrapId').val('');
            alert('You need to have at least 1 wrap!');
        } else {
            $(this).parents('.wrap').remove();
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: you want to re arrange value or deleted value not consider ?

Comment: can you provide fiddle ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `<ul id="#wrapper">` should not have a `#` in it
2. you dont need `e.preventDefault();` in the click handler
3. where you close your list, you have `</li>` where you should have `</ul>`
4. When you get down to just one wrap, you don't want to set `('.wrapId').val('')`, if you do, the next clone will break as it won't have a number to add to
5. the code can be greatly simplified

The below should do what you need. One thing though, if you delete the last "wrap" then add one back, it will use the same number that the deleted wrap had. If you dont want that please let me know.

```js
// Add Wrap
    $('#addWrap').click(function (e) {
        var $cloneElem = $('#wraper li').last().clone();
        var newID = Number( $cloneElem.find('.wrapId').eq(0).val() ) + 1;
        $cloneElem.find('.wrapId').val(newID);
        $('#wraper').append($cloneElem);
        //adjustContainerHeight(); // commented out for demo
    });


// Delete Wrap
    $('#wraper').on('click','.removeWrap',  function (e) {
        if ($('#wraper .wrap').length == 1) {
            $('#wraper .wrap input:not(.wrapId) ').val(''); // you dont want to set wrapId to '' here, if you did, the next clone would break
            alert('You need to have at least 1 wrap!');
        } 
        else $(this).parent('.wrap').remove();
        e.preventDefault(); // maybe you need this if your clicked element is a link or something? maybe not...
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="addWrap" type="button" value="Make Clone" />
<ul id="wraper">
    <li class="wrap">
        <input type="text" class="dateField" value="" name="date" />
        <input type="text" class="timeField" value="" name="time" />
        <input type="text" class="wrapId" value="1" name="wrapId" /> <!-- unhidden for demo-->
        <button class="removeWrap" value="" >Remove</button><!-- added for demo-->
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @DelightedD0D.
I am sorry for rough coding it was typo mistakes. 
Your answer is perfect.